# ASP.NET Web api POST method dynamic parameter is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to have method in web api that receives json, but its structure is dynamic. I tried to use following code, but always value is null.

```
[HttpPost]
public class TestController : Controller
{
   public JsonResult DoJob(dynamic value)
    {
       //Work with parameter
    }     
}
```

Used this json

```
{"testObject":{"property":"value"}, "otherPropery": "otherValue"}
```

**UPDATE:**
This is how I send request from client side

```
value is {"testObject":{"property":"value"}, "otherPropery": "otherValue"}
$http.post("test/dojob",value);
```

Comment: how do you call `Test/DoJob` url?

Comment: /test/dojob. I have redifined default url without 'api' in it.

Comment: show the javascript code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters of controller action methods are bound by their names:

```
var value = { "value": {
  "testObject": { "property": "value" }, 
  "otherPropery": "otherValue"
} };
$http.post("test/dojob",value);
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the case. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think, json result it's equivalent to string if you do

```
[HttpPost]
public class TestController : Controller
{
   public JsonResult DoJob(string value)
    {
       //Work with parameter
    }     
}
```

it should work

Comment: Still the same, value parameter is null.

Comment: how do you call to controller?

Comment: I use angular http service, I will add how I call api from javascript side