# Get dynamic object from query parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way to get a dynamic object from query parameters in an ASP.NET Core WebAPI controller action?

When I try the following I get `queries` as an empty object

```
public object Action([FromQuery] dynamic queries)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the endpoint? A similar question was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33018893/5803406

Comment: Looks like a lord of the rings method (one method to rule them all). FWIW, Even if you could do this, you probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround of customizing a model binder to bind the query string to Dictionary type:

*DynamicModelBinder*

```
public class DynamicModelBinder:IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        var result = new Dictionary<string, dynamic> { };
        var query = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Query;
        if (query == null)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("QueryString", "The data is null");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        foreach (var k in query.Keys)
        {
            StringValues v = string.Empty;
            var flag = query.TryGetValue(k, out v);
            if (flag)
            {
                if (v.Count > 1)
                {
                    result.Add(k, v);
                }
                else { 
                result.Add(k, v[0]);

                }
            }
        }

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

*Controller*

```
public object Action([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DynamicModelBinder))]dynamic queries)
    {
        return queries;
    }
```

*Result*
[image]